# Symbol codes displaying instead

Tags: html, special-characters

I'm trying to create a page with special characters on it, but when It displays to browser it is showing some random character. I tried to set the character to=utf8 based on what i read, but still nothing happens. Example: El Ñino de san agustin displays El Ã‘ino de San Agustin. But when i used `&ntilde;` before ino it displays properly. Is there any other way i can display special characters without inputting &tilde and others to display symbol codes?

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
?>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Test</title>

  </head>
  <body background="images/flower.jpg">
El &ntilde;ino de San Agustin
 El Ñino de San Agustin</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `charset=utf-8` in your `header`? Is you file in UTF-8 character set?

Answer (score 1):

I see you have utf8 in the meta-tag but not in the header.

Have you tried the following?

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Yes it works, but i can't set the charset to utf-8 because im selecting datas from my sql file too, when i used ut8 Ñ becomes (?)

Comment: What charset is the mySQL database?

Comment: you mean the collation of table? I change it to utf8_bin from latin1_swedish, but still displays (?)

Comment: What character set is the php-file?

Comment: utf8 is the character set